# How to extract data from this nested array

Tags: arrays, json, perl, multidimensional-array, data-extraction

I'm trying to extract data from a JSON string generated by my PHP web application.

What I've tried:

```
sub SqlQuery {

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    $SqlQuery = shift;

    my $MYSQLDB     = "db";
    my $SQLuser     = "user";
    my $SQLpassword = "password";

    my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database = $MYSQLDB;host=localhost;port=3306";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $SQLuser, $SQLpassword);

    my $DrugsJson = '';
    my @myjson;

    say "Query is " . $SqlQuery;

    my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
        $SqlQuery, { Slice => {} }
    );

    my $ct = 0;

    foreach my $row ( @$rows ) {

        say "Count: $ct";

        $DrugsJson = $row->{medicine};
        say $DrugsJson;

        @myjson = decode_json($DrugsJson);
        say Dumper @myjson;

        foreach my $row (@myjson) {

            say "Row is " .ref $row;

            foreach my $element ( @$row ) {

                say "Element is " .ref $element;

                foreach my $subelement (@{$element}) {
                    say "SubElement is " . $subelement;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($myjson[0][0]) {
            push @Brand, $_;
        }

        say "Listing brands..";
        say Dumper @Brand;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to read the data containing `"NASOCLEAR NASAL SPRAY","ASCORIL FLU SYRUP","CALPOL 120MG SUSPENSION"` into array `@Brand`, `"SODIUM CHLORIDE 0.65%W/V","CHLORPHENIRAMINE 2MG+PHENYLEPHRINE 5MG","PARACETAMOL 120MG/5ML"` into `@Generic` and so on.

Sample output:

```
Query is SELECT `diagnosis`, `ICDCode`, `ICDVer`, `history`, `examination`, `medicine`, `investigation`, `consultations` FROM `clinical` WHERE `CheckinNo`=85 LIMIT 1
Count: 0
[["NASOCLEAR NASAL SPRAY","ASCORIL FLU SYRUP","CALPOL 120MG SUSPENSION"],["SODIUM CHLORIDE 0.65%W/V","CHLORPHENIRAMINE 2MG+PHENYLEPHRINE 5MG","PARACETAMOL 120MG/5ML"],["1","3","5"],["Drops","mL","mL"],["TDS","BD","TDS"],["5","5","3"],["days","days","days"],"85"]
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'NASOCLEAR NASAL SPRAY',
            'ASCORIL FLU SYRUP',
            'CALPOL 120MG SUSPENSION'
          ],
          [
            'SODIUM CHLORIDE 0.65%W/V',
            'CHLORPHENIRAMINE 2MG+PHENYLEPHRINE 5MG',
            'PARACETAMOL 120MG/5ML'
          ],
          [
            '1',
            '3',
            '5'
          ],
          [
            'Drops',
            'mL',
            'mL'
          ],
          [
            'TDS',
            'BD',
            'TDS'
          ],
          [
            '5',
            '5',
            '3'
          ],
          [
            'days',
            'days',
            'days'
          ],
          '85'
        ];

Row is ARRAY
Element is ARRAY
SubElement is NASOCLEAR NASAL SPRAY
SubElement is ASCORIL FLU SYRUP
SubElement is CALPOL 120MG SUSPENSION
Element is ARRAY
SubElement is SODIUM CHLORIDE 0.65%W/V
SubElement is CHLORPHENIRAMINE 2MG+PHENYLEPHRINE 5MG
SubElement is PARACETAMOL 120MG/5ML
Element is ARRAY
SubElement is 1
SubElement is 3
SubElement is 5
Element is ARRAY
SubElement is Drops
SubElement is mL
SubElement is mL
Element is ARRAY
SubElement is TDS
SubElement is BD
SubElement is TDS
Element is ARRAY
SubElement is 5
SubElement is 5
SubElement is 3
Element is ARRAY
SubElement is days
SubElement is days
SubElement is days
Element is 
Can't use string ("85") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ./sendpresc.pl line 121.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you are getting, after calling `decode_json`, is turned in Perl into an array ref of array refs for all rows but the last one (or following the suggestion in a comment "a reference to an array of array references"), that contains a scalar (the row id). To traverse the JSON you may do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $DrugsJson = '[["NASOCLEAR NASAL SPRAY","ASCORIL FLU SYRUP","CALPOL 120MG SUSPENSION"],["SODIUM CHLORIDE 0.65%W/V","CHLORPHENIRAMINE 2MG+PHENYLEPHRINE 5MG","PARACETAMOL 120MG/5ML"],["1","3","5"],["Drops","mL","mL"],["TDS","BD","TDS"],["5","5","3"],["days","days","days"],"85"]';

my $myjson = decode_json($DrugsJson);

# Traverse the JSON
foreach my $i ( @$myjson ) {
  print "Row is ", ref $i, "\n";
  if( ref $i eq 'ARRAY' ) {
    foreach my $j ( @$i ) {
      print "Sub-element is ", $j, "\n";
    }
  }
  else {
    print "Element is ", $i, "\n";
  }
}

# Create arrays for Brand and Generic
my @Brand   = @{ $myjson->[0] };
my @Generic = @{ $myjson->[1] };

print 'Brand has: ', join(', ', @Brand), "\n";
print 'Generic has: ', join(', ', @Generic), "\n";
```

I have created the bit of code to have a JSON turned into a Perl data structure (I don't have your database.) It is better to receive the JSON in a scalar variable like `$myjson = decode_json($DrugsJson)`. From there, [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) will tell you whether what you have is a ref (a string with "ARRAY", "HASH" and so on) or a scalar (no value).

In order to address the element `$i, $j` of an array ref of array refs, you may use `$myjson->[$i][$j]` which is the compact form of `$myjson->[$i]->[$j]`. You may also turn an array ref into an array using the conversion `@{ $array_ref }`. For simple expressions, you may also use `@$array_ref`. But for an element of an array ref, you need the longer `@{ $myjson->[0] }`.

The output:

```
Row is ARRAY
Sub-element is NASOCLEAR NASAL SPRAY
Sub-element is ASCORIL FLU SYRUP
Sub-element is CALPOL 120MG SUSPENSION
Row is ARRAY
Sub-element is SODIUM CHLORIDE 0.65%W/V
Sub-element is CHLORPHENIRAMINE 2MG+PHENYLEPHRINE 5MG
Sub-element is PARACETAMOL 120MG/5ML
Row is ARRAY
Sub-element is 1
Sub-element is 3
Sub-element is 5
Row is ARRAY
Sub-element is Drops
Sub-element is mL
Sub-element is mL
Row is ARRAY
Sub-element is TDS
Sub-element is BD
Sub-element is TDS
Row is ARRAY
Sub-element is 5
Sub-element is 5
Sub-element is 3
Row is ARRAY
Sub-element is days
Sub-element is days
Sub-element is days
Row is
Element is 85
Brand has:   NASOCLEAR NASAL SPRAY, ASCORIL FLU SYRUP, CALPOL 120MG SUSPENSION
Generic has: SODIUM CHLORIDE 0.65%W/V, CHLORPHENIRAMINE 2MG+PHENYLEPHRINE 5MG, PARACETAMOL 120MG/5ML
```

Comment: Please can we drop the *"array ref of array refs"* idea? It's an array of arrays. If you insist on the "reference" nonsense then it should be "a reference to an array of array references", but remember that this is *JavaScript Object Notation* so there are no references.

Comment: @Borodin, sorry, I may not have been clear. I was talking about the Perl data structure that you get after calling to `decode_json`. I will make the comment clearer.

Comment: Even in Perl, I think the insistence on flagging everything as a *reference* is superfluous. Perl does nested data structures using references: the same way as many other languages. Nowhere else does the confusing idea of references to references arise.

Comment: @Borodin, you are right, in Perl any nested data structure is handled through references. But to me, keeping in mind what they are is the way to remember how to access the insides in the right way. This may be or may not be clearer to other people. Hopefully your comments and mine will get the OP thinking... But that is the way it is. A list in Perl is defined with `( ... )`, and a ref to a list with `[ ... ]`.

Comment: Unless they are dealing with advanced programming, few people are taught that a multi-dimensional array in C consists of multiple arrays stacked end-to-end. *"Keeping in mind what they are"* rather defeats the idea of high-level languages in the first place, and I think it's counter-productive to inflict the idea of references on new learners. There's a reason why `$aa[0][1][2]` is valid Perl